# postMessage not working from parent to iframe

Tags: javascript, cookies, iframe, google-tag-manager

I am trying to send a cookie from my parent page to an iframe.

Here is my postMessage code:

```html
<script>
  try {
    var postObject = JSON.stringify({
      event: 'DOMPageLoad',
      data: '{{Page URL}}'
    });
    parent.postMessage(postObject, 'https://mysite/l/839063/2020-02-26/29bh');
  } catch(e) {
    window.console && window.console.log(e);
  }
  </script>
```

I've tried using this from the iframe to the parent and it works like a charm, but I can't get it to work the other way around.

Here is my eventListener code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(window) {

    addEvent(window, 'message', function(message) {
      try{
      var data = JSON.parse(message.data);
      var dataLayer = window.dataLayer || (window.dataLayer = []);
      if (data.event) {
        dataLayer.push({
          'event': data.event,
          'postMessageData': data
        });
      }
      }catch(e){}
    });

    // Cross-browser event listener
    function addEvent(el, evt, fn) {
      if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener(evt, fn);
      } else if (el.attachEvent) {
        el.attachEvent('on' + evt, function(evt) {
          fn.call(el, evt);
        });
      } else if (typeof el['on' + evt] === 'undefined' || el['on' + evt] === null) {
        el['on' + evt] = function(evt) {
          fn.call(el, evt);
        };
      }
    }

  })(window);
</script>
```

My assumption is that the issue has to do with how I am trying to send the message to the iframe. Right now I am using `parent.postMessage`, but I assume it will need to be something different for the iframe.

[image]

This is probably something really simple, but I am quite new to javascript and simply don't know what I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right about the problem being `parent.postMessage`.  The `parent` property references the parent of the current frame, but here you want to post a message to a child frame.

To access the window of your `iframe`, you'll first need to get the `iframe` somehow.  For example, if your `iframe` has `id="my-iframe"`, you can use this:

```js
var myIframe = document.getElementById('my-iframe');
```

Then you can access the `iframe`'s window using the [contentWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow) property:

```js
myIframe.contentWindow.postMessage...
```

That should do it!

P.S. I see you have `data: '{{Page URL}}'` with quotes, but I don't think you need them.  You should just be able to use `data: {{Page URL}}` if I'm not mistaken.

---

**Edit: Picking the right way to trigger the code**

Connecting this code to the `All Pages` trigger in GTM will probably cause issues, because the `iframe` hasn't necessarily loaded by the time that trigger fires.  I think these are your two best options:

- **Waiting for the `iframe` to tell you it's ready** (probably the best option)
  You could add some code to the `iframe` that posts a message to the parent as soon as it loads.  When the parent receives the message it can send its message to the `iframe`, and be sure the `iframe` is ready for it.
- **Using GTM's `Window Loaded` trigger type** (easy fix, but not great)
  When you create a GTM trigger you will see the `Window Loaded` trigger type.  This will only fire once everything on the page has loaded, including any `iframe`s.  If you have any large images or anything though, the `Window Loaded` event could fire way after your `iframe` is ready, which is just a waste of time.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and that didn't seem to fix it. I am still not able to post the data to the iframe.

Comment: Hey Avenues_Q, I'm sorry that didn't work.  Is the message being posted to the `iframe` immediately when the page loads?  It's possible that the `iframe` hasn't finished loading when the message is posted to it.  That's my best guess at the moment.

Comment: I am using Google Tag Manager to do this and the message is sending on the DOM Page Ready trigger. DO you have any suggestions on how I should set up the trigger? When should it fire?

Comment: For some additional context - I am simply trying to pass a cookie from the parent page to the iframe on page load. 

I don't know if the code I am using is only built to work on a form submit or button click, because it works when I submit a from on the iframe to the parent page, but no dataLayer is created when I try it from the parent page to the iframe.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info.  I edited my answer above to give you some options for how to fire the code.  I think the first option is the best one, but it's a little complicated.  Let me if you have questions about the two options!

Answer (score 0):

I was using Chrome to check the console.log output from the parent window being sent to the child iframe, but I noticed that Chrome hides these logs by default. To view them, you need to open the developer tools and select the dropdown which says 'top' and change it to your iframe.